# Another characterization of complex differentiability Elias Stein

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a quick question which might be trivial, but in the other characterization below. I am just wondering what is the importance of this $\psi(h)$ function other than that it provides us with a way to prove the reverse implication, i.e if we assume (2) is true, then we can divide by h and take the limit as h approaches zero, so we get (1) (Here (1) is regular definition of holomorphic at a point $z_0$.)

I was wondering is there a conceptual idea for this function $\psi$ ?
The book also mentions that from this characterization f is continuous wherever it is holomorphic. Why is that?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $\psi$ is acting as an error term, dependent (linearly, by power series expansion) on $h$, the distance between the two points you are trying to approximately find the difference between.

The intuition is that a holomorphic function can roughly be treated like a linear (being careful with what this means in complex analysis, it's really a small rotation and translation) function for $h$ small. The $\psi$ tells you how roughly.

To notice continuity, take limits:
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}|f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)|=\lim_{h\to 0}(ah+h\psi(h))=0\\
\implies 
\lim_{h\to 0}f(z_0+h)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(z_0)=f(z_0)
$$
where the computation on the right used assumptions on $\psi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot that is very helpful